# Cannot find module '@foo' with ts-jest and monorepo

Tags: typescript, jestjs, es6-modules, ts-jest, monorepo

I have a monorepo utilizing TypeScript, WebPack, and ts-jest. It builds correctly but unit testing fails on one of the sub-projects `./demo` due to:

`Cannot find module '@mlhaufe/graphics/adapters' or its corresponding type declarations.`

**<root>/tsconfig.json**

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./packages",
        "paths": {
            "@mlhaufe/graphics/*": [
                "lib/src/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "references": [
        {
            "path": "./packages/lib"
        },
        {
            "path": "./packages/demo"
        }
    ],
    "files": [],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

**<root>/packages/demo/tsconfig.json**

```json
{
   ...
    "references": [
        {
            "path": "../lib"
        }
    ]
```

**<root>/jest.config.mjs**

```js
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import url from 'url';
import { pathsToModuleNameMapper } from 'ts-jest';
import tsconfig from './tsconfig.json' assert { type: 'json' };

const { compilerOptions } = tsconfig,
    __filename = url.fileURLToPath(import.meta.url),
    __dirname = path.dirname(__filename),
    packageNames = fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './packages'));

/** @type {import('jest').Config} */
export default {
    rootDir: compilerOptions.baseUrl,
    verbose: true,
    testPathIgnorePatterns: [
        '<rootDir>/node_modules/',
    ],
    reporters: [
        'default',
        ['jest-junit', { outputDirectory: './coverage' }]
    ],
    // <https://jestjs.io/docs/next/configuration#projects-arraystring--projectconfig>
    projects: packageNames.map((name) => ({
        displayName: name,
        transform: {
            '^.+\\.mts$': ['ts-jest', { useESM: true }]
        },
        moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'mjs', 'mts'],
        roots: [`<rootDir>`],
        modulePaths: [compilerOptions.baseUrl],
        // required due to ts-jest limitation
        // <https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/guides/esm-support/#support-mts-extension>
        resolver: '<rootDir>/mjs-resolver.ts',
        // Used the path aliases in tsconfig.json
        moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths, {
            prefix: '<rootDir>',
            useESM: true
        }),
        // moduleNameMapper: {
        //     '@mlhaufe/graphics/(.+)': '<rootDir>/packages/lib/src',
        //     '^(\\.\\.?/.*)\\.mjs$': ['$1.mts', '$0']
        // },
        testMatch: [`<rootDir>/packages/${name}/**/*.test.mts`],
        testPathIgnorePatterns: [`<rootDir>/packages/${name}/dist/`]
    }))
};
```

**<root>/package.json**

```json
{
    ...
    "workspaces": [
        "packages/*"
    ],
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=16.0.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "build": "npm run build --workspaces",
        "build:lib": "npm run build --workspace=packages/lib",
        "build:demo": "npm run build --workspace=packages/demo",
        "test": "jest --coverage",
        "test:lib": "jest --selectProjects=lib --coverage",
        "test:demo": "jest --selectProjects=demo --coverage",
        "serve:demo": "npm run serve --workspace=packages/demo"
    },
    ...
}
```

I can't figure out why ts-jest is unable to find the module when webpack+typescript have no trouble. I've also yet to figure out the relationship between settings outside of the `projects` property and those within. My assumption was that those would be global and apply to each project, but I suspect that is not true.

Any feedback would be appreciated. I've yet to see a consistent (modern) article on how this is accomplished.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same problem right now, did you manage to find a solution? Because I'm about to write a custom resolver inspired by `ts-jest-resolver` that will be able to handle also local packages.

Comment: @roomcayz No luck. I had to abandon the effort. I look forward to what you come up with.

Comment: actually I did, but I gave up on transitioning our monorepo to esm for now, it's too much of a hussle - nothing is working, you fix one error, two more pops up - we've decided to wait until the tooling will mature a bit - but I'll post the solution that I've come up with as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as far as I understood the problem: jest is resolving the local modules in a monorepo without transpiling them before. I treat the solution in this answer more like a workaround than like a final thing.

The solution that I've come up with is basically translating the import path to be not treated as an external package, but rather as a path import.

My `jest.config.ts` file:

```js
const config: Config = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts-esm',
  resolver: '<rootDir>/jest.resolve.cjs',
  // the rest of the config is omitted, the above two lines are the important part
}

export default config
```

The `jest.resolve.cjs` file:

```js
const fs = require('node:fs')
const path = require('node:path')
const resolver = require('ts-jest-resolver')

const localModules = new Map(
  fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, 'packages'), { withFileTypes: true })
    .filter((dirent) => dirent.isDirectory())
    .map((dirent) => {
      const directory = path.join(__dirname, 'packages', dirent.name)
      const pkg = require(path.join(directory, 'package.json'))
      const main = path.join(directory, pkg.main)

      return [pkg.name, main]
    }),
)

/**
 * @param {string} path
 * @param {import('jest-resolve').ResolverOptions} options
 * @returns {string}
 */
module.exports = function resolve (path, options) {
  return resolver(localModules.get(path) ?? path, options)
}
```

As you may have figured it out already, all the local modules in my case are stored inside of the `packages` directory - so you may need to adjust it accordingly if it's different for you.

And dear reader: if you have encountered this problem I can safely assume you are advanced enough to understand the code so I'll omit the explanation of it :)